# What does this RewriteRule do and why do I get an error 500?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My website has just stopped working and I keep getting error 500's.  When checking the .htaccess file I see several RewriteRules which when I turn off my website seems to work, although I dont want to leave them off as I'm not sure if I need them or what they do

the rules are below:

```
RewriteRule ^ebay/(.*) ebay/$1 [L]    
RewriteRule ^images/(.*) images/$1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^apollo/(.*) apollo/$1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^ckeditor/(.*) ckeditor/$1 [L]     
RewriteRule ^css/(.*) css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*) js/$1 [L]  
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*) /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/ /index.php [L]
```

can anyone explain what they do, why I may need them, or why I could be getting error 500's?

Comment: what do your logs show?

Comment: the whole first bunch of rules seem pointless. They point to the same place they match. You need to turn on logging for the rewrite module

Comment: how would I turn on logging for the rewrite module?